# Xcode: can't specifiy -Q with -arch arm64

Tags: ios, xcode, arm64

I'm trying to recompile [kivy](https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios) for `arm64` (as Apple requires arm64 apps starting February, 2015) and i'm getting error:

> can't specifiy -Q with -arch arm64

(yes, tool produces output with `specifiy` word).

The problem is that `-Q` is not used:

> MBA-Anton:kivy-ios2 asmirnov$
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -x c -arch arm64 -fmessage-length=115 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -fcolor-diagnostics -std=gnu99 -fmodules -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -Os -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk
>   -fstrict-aliasing -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 -iquote /Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/kivy-ios2/tmp/libffi-3.2.1/build/libffi.build/Release-iphoneos/libffi-iOS.build/ffi-generated-files.hmap
>   -I/Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/kivy-ios2/tmp/libffi-3.2.1/build/libffi.build/Release-iphoneos/libffi-iOS.build/ffi-own-target-headers.hmap
>   -I/Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/kivy-ios2/tmp/libffi-3.2.1/build/libffi.build/Release-iphoneos/libffi-iOS.build/ffi-all-target-headers.hmap
>   -iquote /Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/kivy-ios2/tmp/libffi-3.2.1/build/libffi.build/Release-iphoneos/libffi-iOS.build/ffi-project-headers.hmap
>   -I/Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/kivy-ios2/tmp/libffi-3.2.1/build/Release-iphoneos/include
>   -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
>   -Idarwin_common/include -Idarwin_ios/include -I/Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/kivy-ios2/tmp/libffi-3.2.1/build/libffi.build/Release-iphoneos/libffi-iOS.build/DerivedSources/arm64
>   -I/Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/kivy-ios2/tmp/libffi-3.2.1/build/libffi.build/Release-iphoneos/libffi-iOS.build/DerivedSources
>   -F/Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/kivy-ios2/tmp/libffi-3.2.1/build/Release-iphoneos
>   -no-integrated-as -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/kivy-ios2/tmp/libffi-3.2.1/build/libffi.build/Release-iphoneos/libffi-iOS.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ffi64_x86_64.d
>   --serialize-diagnostics /Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/kivy-ios2/tmp/libffi-3.2.1/build/libffi.build/Release-iphoneos/libffi-iOS.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ffi64_x86_64.dia
>   -c /Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/kivy-ios2/tmp/libffi-3.2.1/darwin_ios/src/x86/ffi64_x86_64.c
>   -o /Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/kivy-ios2/tmp/libffi-3.2.1/build/libffi.build/Release-iphoneos/libffi-iOS.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ffi64_x86_64.o
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/as:
>   can't specifiy -Q with -arch arm64 clang: error: assembler command
>   failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"-no-integrated-as" is not needed, works without it

Comment: I must use -no-integrated-as with my source code, so what is the fix?

Comment: I have the same problem. would you clarify how can I fix it?